# Getting only white noise when playing sound by Audio Track Class

Tags: android, audio

I want to play a mp3 with mono and stereo effect. Currently i am working on play stereo effect I have read all the documents, but i am getting only white noise.
my code is:

```
public class AudioTest extends Activity 
{       byte[] b;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    AndroidAudioDevice device = new AndroidAudioDevice( );
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                      
    File f=new File("/sdcard/lepord.mp3");
    try {
        FileInputStream in=new FileInputStream(f);
        int size=in.available();
        b=new byte[size];
        in.read(b);
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while( true )
    {
        device.writeSamples(b);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }           
}
}
```

and my AndroidAudioDevice class is:

```
public class AndroidAudioDevice
{
    AudioTrack track;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[158616];
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public AndroidAudioDevice( )
    {
        int minSize =AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize( 44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT );        
        track = new AudioTrack( AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100, 
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 
                158616, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);        
        Log.e(""," sizewe are using for track buffer is 158616");
        track.setStereoVolume(.6f,.6f);
        track.play();    
    }    
    public void writeSamples(byte[] b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("","bytes to be write in track is "+b.length );
        fillBuffer(b);
        track.write( buffer, 0, b.length );
    }       
    private void fillBuffer( byte[] samples )
    {
        Log.e("","track buffer length="+buffer.length+"    samle length"+samples.length );
        if( buffer.length < samples.length )
            buffer = new byte[samples.length];
        for( int i = 0; i < samples.length; i++ )
            buffer[i] = (byte)(samples[i] * Byte.MAX_VALUE);;
    }
}
```

first i am not getting any sound rather than white noise, i just want to play a sound by AudioTrack and then i will work on mono and stereo sound effect 
please help me
Thanks in advance.*

Comment: AudioTrack docs "It allows streaming of PCM audio ", mp3 is not PCM audio

Comment: Yes. The characteristics of an entropy coded bitstream is essentially a nearly random stream of bits.  However, `fillBuffer()` also looks really broken too.  What precisely are you trying to achieve here?  The output format is stereo 16-bit PCM, but this being Java, you're going to have to pack it into the output buffer a byte at a time.  What type did you imagine the input samples had?  Doesn't look like floating point to me.

Comment: thanks i am looking forward to it. i am using jlayer decoder to decode the mp3 to pcm but now i am not getting any sound,am i missig something.please help me i got fed up with this.

Comment: first: when i take a .aiff pcm file as a input (for checking the code)i found the sound but when i play a large sound file in auditrack there is a gap between buffers sounds.so please tell me how to fix this gap.
second: in pcm format the file becomes very large.and could you tell me how to convert file from mp3 to pcm efficiently i have heard about some native libarary like mpg123 to decode the sound in real time ..please tell me how to use them .thanks in advance

Comment: although wave is a pcm formate but it is not playing in audiotrack,why??